# Making public parent destructor private in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

when I try to compile the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};

class B : A {
private:
    using A::A;
    using A::~A;
};
```

I get the following compiler error message:

```
error: 'A::~A' names destructor
```

Any reason why this is the case?

The bigger reason why I would like to do this is to be able to use templates to create a container that can theoretically store any type by instantiation through a container < container > (which also defines Node class), but would like make things less confusing for the user by creating a derived version of container called C_Node that has everything except the Node class private. The end goal is to allow the user to declare container < container > C, then push a C_Node into C via upcasting.

If there's a better way to do this in C++, please let me hear it.

Comment: You can't inherit destructors.  Unless you are doing some sort of resource acquisition manually, you should never need to write a destructor.

Comment: C++ provides `std::vector`, `std::shared_ptr`, and (if needed) `std::enable_shared_from_this`.  Can't those be used to solve the problem?

Comment: NathanOliver: Okay; I suppose that is a fair assumption to make once I get more experience coding. Thanks. Elijay: Vector only lets you store 1 type of object, but I want the flexibility to store more. I haven't heard of the other functions, but I think I have more than enough to go on for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In nearly all cases, you shouldn't be making destructors private. A destructor needs to be public so that the compiler can call it when an object reaches the end of it's lifetime. There's also no reason to try to "hide" the destructor of a base class.

No one should be calling a destructor explicitly, except in very low-level code such as the kind that uses raw unions.

Have you seen the `std::any` class? `std::any` is a class that can store any type, and I think it does what you're trying to do:

```
// main.cpp
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using std::any;
    using std::string; 

    any x = 10;
    // x can be assigned any type
    x = string("hello");

    // You can get the type x contains safely using any_cast
    std::cout << std::any_cast<string>(x) << '\n';
}
```

`std::any` was added to the language in C++17, which came out in 2017. You can use it by adding the compilation flag `-std=c++17` on gcc or clang!

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: I'll give the <any> library a look through. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a feature that exists, nor does it really make sense to.

`using A::A` doesn't inherit the base constructor. It synthesises a `B(A's args)` in that place, and with that access level, which forwards its arguments to the base ctor.

There are no arguments for a destructor, so this feature isn't there. *Could* it have been added? Sure. But there's no real reason to do so.

You can simply write `~B() = default;` to get the effect you're after, but I strongly advise against making destructors private.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that this was a decision made by the "standards committee", but thankfully, it is still fine since it seems destructors are rarely explicitly called as a general code of conduct.

Comment: Even when they are, it's a low level action you shouldn't be going out of your way to try to prevent.